# MultiLine regex matching python

Tags: python, regex, multiline, python-re

Below is my multi-line string.

```
sample='''
blah
blah
blah
blah
text.get(
'hi'
'you're
'welcome'
)
text.get(
'hi'
'i'm
'here'
> )
blah
blah
blah
```

I want to match based on the symbol `>` and get the relevant text in the in the brackets

```
text.get(
'hi'
'i'm
'here'
> )
```

I tried this code
`text(.+)\((.*?)>(.*?)\)` and it matches both the instances of text.get.Can someone please help on this

Comment: You need to use the `re.DOTALL` flag to allow `.*` to match across lines.

Comment: Do you wish to return the string containing the four lines `"'hi'"`, `"'i'm"`, `"'here'"` and `"> "`? Incidentally I think you mean parentheses (`"("` and `">"`), not brackets (`"["` and `"]"`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yoy can use

```py
\btext\.\w+\([^()]*\n> \)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SNdAOu/1). *Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `text\.` - a `text.` substring
- `\w+\(` - one or more word  chars and then an open parenthesis
- `[^()]*` - zero or more chars other than parentheses
- `\n> \)` - a newline, space and close parenthesis.

If you need to capture unknown parts of the match add the groups, e.g.

```py
\btext\.(\w+)\(([^()]*)\n> \)
```

In Python, do not forget to use  the raw string literal: `r'...'`.